# Como borrar o limpiar un archivo xml

Tags: javascript

Necesito borrar o limpiar mi xml en javascript que esta de esta forma

```
<markers>
<marker name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Young Henrys" address="76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW" lat="-33.898113" lng="151.174469" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Hunter Gatherer" address="Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" type="bar"/>
<marker name="The Potting Shed" address="7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, NSW" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" type="bar"/>

<marker name="Nomad" address="16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Three Blue Ducks" address="43 Macpherson Street, Bronte, NSW" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Single Origin Roasters" address="60-64 Reservoir Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.881123" lng="151.209656" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Red Lantern" address="60 Riley Street, Darlinghurst, NSW" lat="-33.874737" lng="151.215530" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

Como lo podría hacer?

Comment: Limpiarlo de que manera, que quieres quitar?

Comment: los datos que estan dentro de markers

Comment: Te dejo estos recursos http://www.w3big.com/es/dom/dom-nodes-remove.html ya que no se muy bien como tratarlo con xml, pero debe ser algo como el primer ejemplo del link